# How do I unittest when having an automapper map to existing object and using nsubstitute

Tags: automapper, nsubstitute, automapper-6

I am using Automapper 6.2.1 and by that removed all statics and instead I am injecting `IMapper`.

I am using NSubstitute for mocking.

I have a bit of code where I map two existing objects.

```
public class Person1 {
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class Person2 {
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

...

_mapper.Map(person2, person1);
```

My mapping will replace `Value2` in `person1`.

I am thereafter using `person1` with the modified value.

Is it possible to "return" a different person1 from my mock? And how can I do that, if possible?

**EDIT**

Yes, my question is how I can mock my `_mapper` correctly and "return" a different person1 (**by ref**) using NSubstitute.

person1 is a reference object meaning that in the real implementation Value2 from person2 will replace Value2 in person1. But in my unit test I failed to simulate this scenario.

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know how to mock `Map` method?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information provided in the question to answer this. Please see the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) documentation for help with this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify Person1 argument inside *Do* method if you don't use result parameter of *Map* (it will be null)

```
_mapper
    .When(x => x.Map(person2, person1))
    .Do(x =>
        {
            var person1Arg = x.Arg<Person1>();
            person1Arg.Value1 = "value-1";
            person1Arg.Value2 = "value-2";
        });

//map and use person1
_mapper.Map(person2, person1);
```

Or you can return new Person1 object from *Map*, but in this case original person1 was not modified

```
_mapper.Map(person2, person1)
    .Returns(new Person1
             {
                 Value1 = "value-1",
                 Value2 = "value-2"
             });

//then map and use resultPerson1 instead of person1
var resultPerson1 = _mapper.Map(person2, person1);
```